# How to post File and JSON object from OkHttpClient to Spring Boot controller

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, kotlin, okhttp

I'm attempting to send a File and an object in JSON using OKHttpClient to a Spring Boot controller but I'm running into several errors.

Here's the controller:

```
data class UploadRequest(
  val station: String,
  val originator: String,
  val group: String,
  val personId: Long? = null)

@PostMapping("/api/external/upload")
fun receiveUpload(
  @RequestBody uploadRequest: UploadRequest,
  @RequestParam(name = "file") file: MultipartFile,
  @RequestHeader("Authorization") authorization: String
): ResponseEntity<Any> {
  // do stuff
}
```

Here's my latest attempt of posting code

```
data class Details(
   val station: String,
   val originator: String,
   val group: String,
   val personId: Long? = null
)

fun postData(details: Details, file: File) {

val myJsonBody = Gson().toJson(details, Details::class.java)

val myBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
  .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart(
    "file", file.name,
    file.asRequestBody("application/octet-stream".toMediaTypeOrNull())
  )
  .addPart(myJsonBody.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())
  .build()

val myRequest = Request.Builder()
  .url(URL)
  .addHeader("Authorization", SECRET_KEY)
  .post(myBody)
  .build()

val myResponse = client.newCall(myRequest).execute()

}
```

With this I'm getting the following error on my Controller side:

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.example.UploadRequest.<init>, parameter originator...
```

I *am* able to successfully post the object if I do my URL like so:

```
URL.toHttpUrl().let {
  HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme(it.scheme)
    .host(it.host)
    .port(it.port)
    .addPathSegments(it.pathSegments.joinToString("/"))
    .addQueryParameter("station", details.station)
    .addQueryParameter("originator", details.originator)
    .addQueryParameter("group", details.group)
    .build()
}
```

So if I explicitly name out each query parameter and don't include it in the `myBody` then it's successful, but it just seems like I should be able to send it as a JSON object also and that is what I would prefer to do.

Comment: In Spring query params have straightforward integration with Multipat handling, which explains the last bit of the question. As how to send the JSON, you can tell Spring not to look in RequestBody, but a named part like this https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests#using-requestpart